# Python search path wrong, but only in Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos

I am creating a larger logical package spread out over many directories, like so:

```
[projects root]/projectname1/lib/python/logicalpackage/__init__.py
[projects root]/projectname1/lib/python/logicalpackage/projectname1/__init__.py
[projects root]/projectname2/lib/python/logicalpackage/__init__.py
[projects root]/projectname2/lib/python/logicalpackage/projectname2/__init__.py
```

The idea is to be able to do this:

```
import logicalpackage.projectname1 as p1
import logicalpackage.projectname2 as p2
```

after having a script in .bashrc or $profile (bash and PowerShell, respectively) that will glob over `[projects root]/*/lib/python/` and import the packages it finds.

I know that [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html) is used for this, by sticking that snippet in `__init__.py` (`from pkgutil import extend_path; __path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__`), and I can get everything to work fine across all systems when I do so. My question, though, is why when I *don't* use pkgutil, this still works fine, but only on some platforms--particularly, in OSX and Ubuntu (10 and 12 that I've seen), it works, but in Windows (7) it doesn't. What I worry is that there is some side-effect of using pkgutil that I'm not considering.

The specific non-working behavior is that PYTHONPATH appears to be constructed correctly after that script is run (in the `.bashrc` equivalent in PowerShell), i.e. I can debug print PYTHONPATH from within Python and it is identical to the path constructed on another platform. However, `from projectname1 import foo` succeeds, and `from projectname2 import bar` fails (presumably because projectname2 is globbed later by alpha). That's actually the behavior I would expect without pkgutil. Why isn't that the behavior in OSX and Ubuntu? Is this problem from some pathing mechanism of Windows or PowerShell, or the Python binaries as compiled on Windows, or something else entirely?

EDIT: Adding the below for more clarity:

```
# d:\projects> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH","d:\\projects\\projectname1\\lib\python;d:\\projects\\projectname2\\lib\\python;")
# d:\projects> echo $env:PYTHONPATH
# d:\\projects\\projectname1\\lib\python;e:\\projects\\projectname2\\lib\\python;
# d:\projects> python

import sys
sys.path
# => ['', '..python install dir..\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 'd:\\projects\\projectname1\\lib\\python', 'd:\\projects\\projectname2\\lib\\python', ...usual stuff...]
import logicalpackage
logicalpackage.__path__
# => ['d:\\projects\\projectname1\\lib\\python\\logicalpackage']
import logicalpackage.projectname1 as p1
import logicalpackage.projectname2 as p2

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# ImportError: No module named projectname2
# exit()
```

replace the empty `__init__.py` with the pkgutils code mentioned above

```
# d:\projects> python
import sys
sys.path
# => ['', 'D:\\usr\\Python27_32bit\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 'd:\\projects\\projectname1\\lib\\python', 'd:\\projects\\projectname2\\lib\\python', 'd:\\projects', '...etc...']
import logicalpackage
logicalpackage.__path__
# => ['d:\\projects\\projectname1\\lib\\python\\logicalpackage', 'd:\\projects\\projectname2\\lib\\python\\logicalpackage']
import logicalpackage.projectname1 as p1
import logicalpackage.projectname2 as p2
```

Note: No exception. Having the exception go away after appending to the module path via pkgutil is the expected behavior (to me, and to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html))--Python shouldn't append to the module path unless I explicitly declare it. What I am wondering is why no exception occurs on Ubuntu (in other words, why it appends to the module path **without** being explicitly declared), whether or not I include the pkgutils snippet.

Comment: do you understand the difference between `import a.b as b` and `import b` when `b`'s parent directory is added to `sys.path` by mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting at. Do you mean that `b` is the same module in both examples, and that the mistakenly appended directory is `a`? Unless I'm mistaken, `import a.b as b` means `a` is a package (i.e., a directory containing an `__init__.py`), and a search path appended to `sys.path` is not, typically.

Comment: yes, you should not add directories with `__init__.py` to `sys.path`. You said: *"`from projectname1 import foo` succeeds"*. It should fail if your `sys.path` is correct. The last two examples that you added look like they should i.e., the 1st should fail, 2nd -- succeed. Or are you saying that they behave differently depending on platform?

Comment: They behave differently depending on platform, yes. The example directory structure in the question is representative (i.e., there aren't extra files that aren't the ones explicitly enumerated), and from the examples up there you can see that sys.path has the lib/python directories, not the individual packages.

Comment: I reworded the last paragraph to make my expectations a little more clear, the way I had it before was slightly confusing. My question is about why the module path includes both packages in Ubuntu without pkgutils, but only includes the first (by alpha) in Windows, unless I add the pkgutils snippet.

Comment: Let's start simple: `from projectname1 import foo` should fail on all platforms (both my previous comments are about it). Provide `sys.path` and the directory structure for platforms where it succeeds.

Comment: We're getting into the weeds on something that isn't really my concern. Don't worry about `from projectname1 import foo`, that was something in my question that was actually a red herring. The actual concern is the platform difference.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and I see the correct `ImportError` for `projectname2`. There might be something wrong with your environment. Can you reproduce 'no exception' case with empty `__init__.py`? Also you should understand the difference between `from logicalpackage.projectname1 import foo` and `from projectname1 import foo` and why the latter must fail in correctly configured environment regardless of other issues that you might have.

Comment: Ah ha, fun fact, I can replicate it, but only in a specific environment. If I start clean, it works the expected way. There's evidently something being bootstrapped that I don't know about, so I'll look there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what ended up being the issue. It turns out that `pkgutils.extend_path` will work for EVERY module within an extended logical package, as long as it is contained within the FIRST instance of that logical package in `PYTHONPATH`. In both environments, `PYTHONPATH` was being prepended with an `environment` module contained within `logicalpackage`, which included `extend_path`. In the Windows environment, that prepended path didn't actually contain anything. My failure was basically in not recognizing that `extend_path` will extend all over logical packages in `PYTHONPATH` even if particular modules within that logical package don't contain `extend_path`, as long as the first instance contains the `pkgutils` snippet.